# cbind error with check.names

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is an example where `cbind` fails with an error when `check.names=TRUE` is set.

```
data(airquality)
airQualityBind = cbind(airquality, airquality, check.names = TRUE)
```

Can anyone explain how to get this to work. I understand that `cbind` is a call to `data.frame` and the following works:

```
airQualityBind = data.frame(airquality, airquality, check.names = TRUE)
```

but I would like to understand why `cbind` throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

Your `cbind` call fails not because you have duplicated names, but because `check.names` isn't a formal argument of `cbind.data.frame`. It actually passes your `check.names` argument down the line to `data.frame` itself, and this fails because it *also* passes a `check.names=FALSE` argument. Thus the error is one of duplicated formal arguments to `data.frame`, *not* duplicated column names in the data frames.

To get it to work, just do `cbind(airquality, airquality)` (which will result in duplicated column names) or `data.frame(airquality, airquality)` (which will deduplicate them).

Comment: I understand this, but surely that means that `cbind` is not behaving correctly?

Comment: Why do you believe this?

Comment: Quoting the help file `For the "data.frame" method of cbind these can be further arguments to data.frame such as stringsAsFactors.`

Comment: I suggest you take this up with the R development team.